# Azure API Management not working with azure service

Tags: azure

I have 2 azure accounts. I did same for both account as below.
Assume the account names are as below.

- Account A
- Account B

I have created API in .NET core and then published it on Azure service.
Then I mapped service it with end points using Azure API Management.

In **Account A** everything is workin.

When I try to access **Account B** through the service, it works, but when I try to call it through the API it's returning me 404 error.

I checked trace of both request and I saw that for **Account B** api inspector has missing some info.

[image]

Comment: are these 2 separate APIMs?

Comment: yes. 2 different accounts

Comment: Can you post OpenApi and Policies of your APIs?

Comment: @MarkusMeyer,  I haven't added any policies

Comment: And how do you specify the backend?

Comment: @markus meyer I have mapped web services URL with api